# Weak derivative of $|x^2 − x+\frac {1}{5}| $ on $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

$f(x) = |x^2 − x+\frac {1}{5}|$. Let $g$ be a function in $C^\infty_0(0,1)$ which means differentiable function with compact support. There exists $[a,b]\subset (0,1)$ such that $\int _0^1 f’(x)g(x)dx= -\int _a^b f(x)g’(x)dx$. How to proceed then? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that by the chain rule, the ordinary derivative of $f$ is $f'(x) = \text{sgn}(x^2 - x + \frac{1}{5})(2x - 1)$. It would make sense to try to show that $f'$ is the weak derivative of $f$. Alternatively, if you can show that $f$ is Lipschitz, then by Sobolev space results it follows that $f'$ is the weak derivative of $f$ (a.e.).